# Add a header to a cppnet-lib response object

Tags: c++, boost, cpp-netlib

I would like to add a header to a cppnet-lib basic_response object. However, I am getting compilation errors.

I can add a header to a basic_request as follows which compiles ok:

```
boost::network::http::basic_request<boost::network::http::tags::http_server> request;
request << header("test", "test");
```

However, doing the same for a response object as follows receives a compilation error:

```
boost::network::http::basic_response<boost::network::http::tags::http_server> response;
response << header("test", "test");
```

Compilation error:

```
 'headers_container_type': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (header.hpp)
 'value_type': is not a member of boost::network::http::basic_response<boost::network::http::tags::http_server> (header.hpp)
 syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'value_type' (header.hpp)
```

This would suggest that this isn't possible on a response object, but following the following page seems to suggest it is. I'm obviously going wrong somewhere!

Documentation: http://cpp-netlib.org/0.8/reference_http_response.html

My environment is:

- Visual Studio 2013 (building as Release)
- Boost 1.55
- cppnet-lib: 0.11.0

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you forget to include some header where the server defined. Please, revise your include section.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you're using the wrong documentation since you're using version 0.11.0 (I suggest you use 0.11.1, which has a lot of bug fixes on top of 0.11.0). Here's the link you actually want for the 0.11.0 documentation:

http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.0/reference/http_server.html#response-object

Second, you'd want to add headers directly to the response object's `headers` member. No need to use functions to do this:

```
struct my_server {
  void operator(server::request const& req, server::response & res) {
    // do something with the request and/or response
    res.headers.push_back(server::response::header("Name", "value"));
    // do more things
  }
  // ...
};
```